# NIntegrate with an arbitrary number of variables

Tags: numerical-integration, variable-definitions

I need to evaluate `NIntegrate` with a variable number of variables.

Here's a concrete example. I'll accept an answer that finds a way to make the example work. I want to calculate the following integral:

$$\int_0^1 \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right) \prod_{i=1}^n\mathrm{d}x_i = \frac{n}{2} $$

where $n$ is the number of variables. This particular integral can be separated into independent integrals, but in general this is not possible. I chose it because it is a simple example.

In Mathematica, we start by defining `n`, say:

```
n = 4;
```

Then I try to evaluate the following command:

```
NIntegrate[Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}], 
    Sequence@@Table[{x[i], 0, 1}, {i, 1, n}]]
```

and it gives an error. What I'm trying to do here is use `x[1], x[2], ...,x[n]` as variables of integration.

Note that `Integrate` does work. So the problem is restricted to `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Does `Evaluate[Sequence@@Table[...]]`inside `NIntegrate` solve your issue?

Comment: @IstvánZachar yes!! Thanks

Comment: `NIntegrate[Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}], ##] & @@ 
 Table[{x[i], 0, 1}, {i, 1, n}]` ?

Comment: @andre that works too. Thanks

Comment: The idea to use `NIntegrate[...,##] @@ Table[...]` comes from the documentation of `SlotSequence` (`##`) where there is a example of `NIntegrate[...]` over 1000 variables (see Application)